# High dimensional Fubini?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I understand how Fubini Theorem works when we have product space $\left(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2, \mathcal{A}_1\times\mathcal{A}_2,P_1\times P_2\right)$. I am looking at a slightly different question.

Suppose I have a probability triple $\left(\times_1^{2n} \Omega, \times_1^{2n}\mathcal{A},\times_1^{2n}P\right)$. I have $2n$ r.v.'s $X_1,\cdots,X_n,Y_1,\cdots,Y_{n}$ defined on this space, and for each $i$, $X_i$ only depends on the $i$-th coordinate. Let $f$ be a measurable function. In what sense, is the following true?

$$\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(X_1,\cdots,Y_n\right)\right] = \int_{\Omega_{n+1}\times\cdots\Omega_{2n}} \left\{\int_{\Omega_1\times\cdots\Omega_{n}}f\left(X_1,\cdots,Y_n\right)\,d\left(P_1\times\cdots P_n\right)\right\}\,d\left(P_{n+1}\times\cdots P_{2n}\right)$$

Does Fubini theorem apply here? Namely, is it true that

$$\int_{\Omega_1\times\cdots\Omega_n} f\left(X_1,\cdots,X_n,Y_1,\cdots,Y_n\right)\,d \left(\times_{i=1}^n P_i\right)$$

is a random variable on $\Omega_{n+1}\times\cdots\Omega_{2n}$? How would Fubini applies in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think at the very beginning, it should be $\sigma(A_{1}\times A_{2})$ rather than $A_{1}\times A_{2}$. Given $\sigma$-algebras $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$, in general $A_{1}\times A_{2}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

For the question, let's consider $n=2$, so we have four variables $x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2}$.

There is a canonical identification that $(x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2})=((x_{1},x_{2}),(y_{1},y_{2}))$, as a result one can actually prove that $\sigma(A_{1}\times A_{2}\times A_{3}\times A_{4})=\sigma(\sigma(A_{1}\times A_{2})\times\sigma(A_{3}\times A_{4}))$.

For the measures issue, with that identification, one can prove that $P_{1}\otimes P_{2}\otimes P_{3}\otimes P_{4}=(P_{1}\otimes P_{2})\otimes(P_{3}\otimes P_{4})$.

If $f$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(A_{1}\times A_{2}\times A_{3}\times A_{4})$ and integrable, with that identification and the usual Fubini Theorem, one has
\begin{align*}
&\int_{\Omega_{1}\times\Omega_{2}\times\Omega_{3}\times\Omega_{4}}f(x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2})d(P_{1}\otimes P_{2}\otimes P_{3}\otimes P_{4})\\
&=\int_{\Omega_{1}\times\Omega_{2}}\left(\int_{\Omega_{3}\times\Omega_{4}}f((x_{1},x_{2}),(y_{1},y_{2}))d(P_{3}\otimes P_{4})\right)d(P_{1}\otimes P_{2})\\
&=\int_{\Omega_{3}\times\Omega_{4}}\left(\int_{\Omega_{1}\times\Omega_{2}}f((x_{1},x_{2}),(y_{1},y_{2}))d(P_{1}\otimes P_{2})\right)d(P_{3}\otimes P_{4}).
\end{align*}

For random variables $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},X_{4}$, if $f$ is such that $f(X_{1},X_{2},Y_{1},Y_{2})$ is measurable and integrable, then the corresponding formula holds.

Comment: I probably misused notation. The book I have use $\mathcal{A}^n$ to represent "the product $\sigma$-field generated from sets of the from $A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$, where $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$". Anyway, I wonder where we use the fact that $X_i$ only depends on the $i$-th coordinate?

Comment: I overlooked your sentence that "depends on the $i$-th coordinate", by the way, then what is the domain of each $X_{i}$?

Comment: If I'm understanding my textbook correctly, all $X_i$'s (as well as $Y_i$'s) are defined on the big product space, and have domain $\mathbb{R}$. In my case, all $\Omega_i$'s. $\mathcal{A}_i$'s, and $P_i$'s are the same.

Comment: You have several combinations. If $X_{1}=X_{1}(x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2})$ (which means its domain is the whole $\Omega_{1}\times\cdots\Omega_{4}$) and so are those $X_{2},...$, then I require that $\varphi_{1}(x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2})=f(X_{1}(x_{1},...),X_{2}(x_{1},...),Y_{1}(x_{1},...),Y_{2}(x_{1},...))$ to be measurable and integrable.

Comment: Or you have the combination like $X_{1}=X_{1}(x_{1})$ (which means its domain is only $\Omega_{1}$) and so are those $X_{2},...$, then I require that $\varphi_{2}(x_{1},...,y_{2})=f(X_{1}(x_{1}),...,Y_{2}(y_{2}))$ to be measurable and integrable.

Comment: Or trickier condition like $X_{1}=X_{1}(x_{1},...,y_{2})=\widetilde{X}_{1}(x_{1})$ (which means its domain is the whole big product, but actually it is assumed to be having the same value with another $\widetilde{X}_{1}$ which is only having domain $\Omega_{1}$) or the mixed conditions, and similarly I require that $\varphi_{3}(x_{1},...,y_{2})=f(X_{1},...)$ to be measurable and integrable.

Comment: No matter what, actually what exactly $X_{1},...,Y_{2}$ look like does not matter that much, the point is, you need to make sure the whole $f(X_{1},...,Y_{2})$ must be measurable and integrable to the big one.

Comment: You see, the measurability is the most annoying thing. If it is measurable, to justify the integrability, one always puts the absolute value to the integrand, and try to use Tonelli and do some inequalities $<\cdots<\cdots$ and end up with $<\infty$, then it is integrable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm still thinking about those. The theorem I'm reading actually deals with "outer expectation" (or called "outer integral"). The thing I'm trying to make rigorous is actually how to justify "for fixed $X_1,\cdots,X_n$'" (since they are not fixed numbers, after all!), and doing some things, and then "take expectation with respect to $X_1,\cdots,X_n$"

Comment: Outer integral doesn't require the mapping to integrate to be measurable, so that's not my big concern here. Rather I want to clearly understand at each step, over what sample space and probability measure we are integrating.

Comment: What is the book are you reading? I might take a look what is really going on there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72334/discussion-between-iseliget-and-user284331).